# Advice on running 3 USB Devices with Raspbmc

Tags: raspbmc

My Setup:
Rasp. Pi with Raspbmc,
1TB external HDD,
TP-Link WLAN dongle,
USB IR-remote,
USB Hub (own powersource)

Everthing works fine when directly plugged into the pi. But neither the HDD nor the dongle are working when plugged into the hub. (note: The remote always works and is plugged into the hub. Lights are on (dongle and hdd))

I'm not sure if it is configuration error or a problem with power supply or ??? Any advice apreaciated!

thx

Comment: Can you specify what kind of power supplies you are using, which USB hub, and if there is any messages in the system logs when you plug in any of the devices in the hub?

Answer (score 1):

For me the Solution was to plug all 3 devices into the hub. Now only the hub is connected to the PI and seems to be working... still dunno why or why not before